# compare two face by opencv in java

Tags: java, opencv, face-recognition

i have db name **verifiDB** [like here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#preparing-the-data) and have a method for load all faces from DB and a **verifi.pgm** face. all ***.pgm** images are *cropped face* and *grayscale* and equals *resolution*. so I need to compare **verifi.pgm** by all of DB faces.

This is my code in java language:

```
public void Verifi_Face() {  
Mat verifi_img = Highgui.imread("Verifi.pgm");
    for(int i=1; i<500; i++){
        final File folder = new File(String.format("verifiDB/s%a", i));
        if(folder.exists()){
            for(int j=1; j<4; j++){
                    Mat img_test = Highgui.imread(String.format("%a/%b.pgm", folder, j));
                    // @@ how to compate two face? (verifi_img and img_test's)
                }
        }else{
            continue;
        }           
    }
}
```

i just need to compare faces in @@ line.
can help Anyone me, please?

Comment: Did you find any answer to your question?